# Dialog.ask() how to call the same method again

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator

I want to check if the network connection is available or not. If it's not available then i am showing a dialog and on click of ok button in the dialog then again i need to check the network connection and so on. Here i am calling the same method again and again., The problem is on click of ok button in the dialog its calling the same method, but the dialog is not getting closed.

Anybody have an idea how to close the dialog if we call the same method again and again.

Eg

```
private void checkConnection()
{
      if (!networkAvailable())
     {

         int reply = Dialog.ask(Dialog.OK,"Network not available");
         if (reply == Dialog.OK)
          {
              checkConnection();
           }

}
```

Thanks
Mindus

Comment: Don't you think this will occur cyclic process...?????

Comment: yes, i want to implement this process

Answer (score 0):

Here is an implementation of the above that is processed in a loop rather than recursively, which makes it easier to manage the end conditions:

```
private void checkConnection() {
  if (!networkAvailable()) {
    boolean networkOK = networkAvailable();
    int reply = Dialog.ask(Dialog.D_OK,"Network not available");
    while (reply == Dialog.OK && !networkOK) {
      networkOK= networkAvailable();
      if ( !networkOK) {
        reply = Dialog.ask(Dialog.D_OK,"Network not available");
      }
    } // end of while loop
  }
} // end of method
```

This code could be further optimised, but as shown, demonstrates the required steps in an obvious fashion.

You could also limit the number of times round the loop if you wanted too.

However I have a couple of reservations.

From a technical perspective I don't know what the method networkAvailable() does.  It might be blocking, in which case we need to rework this code to get it off the Event Thread.

But I guess my major concern is that I am not sure this is a good user experience.  I think you need to look at this from the user's perspective, and think about what they would want to happen if there was no network available.  I am not convinced giving them a dialog like this is the optimal solution.

Answer (score -1):

By seeing your approach you there is cyclic process of checking internet connection it will only end-up when there in and internet connection.

the other way to close this dialog is to set a counter variable.

Try this code :

```
public static final int mCounter = 1;

private void checkConnection() {
    if (!networkAvailable()) {
        if (mCounter != 5) {
            int reply = Dialog.ask(Dialog.OK, "Network not available");
            if (reply == Dialog.OK) {
                mCounter++;
                checkConnection();
            }
    } else {
    mCounter = 1;
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Thread.sleep(60000);
                    checkConnection();
                }
            }).start();
        }
    }
}
```

as this counter variable will be at 5 this dialog will be dismissed.

after one minute this thread will wakes up and again your internet check method will continue.

Comment: This code looks faulty to me.  I think it could invoke Dialog when not on the event thread, and my very quick review  suggests that it will never stop recursively calling checkConnection().  Can you please review and correct?

Comment: @PeterStrange please read the requirement given in question user wants to check internet connection constantly. and also want to close the dialog. so i don't think there is any other solution instead of this and if any other available then please provide.

Comment: Two things: (1) code that does not work is not a solution to any problem - does your code work? (2) the problem here can easily be solved by a number of methods, the simplest being to remove the recursive invocation of the code and 'loop' until some end conditions are meet.  The end conditions could be network is available or some counter is exceeded, or user responds NO to the Dialog.

Comment: @PeterStrange then there must you had checked my code. better you answer this question and help the user to find the solution.

Comment: "better you answer this question " but wouldn't it also be useful if you corrected your own code?  I think the way you have done it can work, just not as currently coded.  Also I have supplied an answer to this question on another forum, see here: http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Dialog-ask-how-to-call-the-same-method-again/td-p/2777829

Comment: Also supplied answer here, since it appears that this code will not be corrected.